# Canonical & Titles on Variable Filters

Tags: page-title

The issue with both the Canonical and Titles are they do not change on the Brand filter level and I cannot figure out how to change them. For example:

URL: http://shop.crownvisioncenter.com/womens/sunglasses/burberry

Title: Sunglasses | Crown Vision Center

Canonical Tag: //shop.crownvisioncenter.com/womens/sunglasses

Title Should Be: Women's Burberry Sunglasses | Crown Vision Center

Canonical Should Be: //shop.crownvisioncenter.com/womens/sunglasses/burberry

Does any one know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

To customize `canonical url` as per your requirement you need to extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_view_prepareLayout`. For reference you will find [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/avid-canonical-url.html) extension helpful and its free. But for your requirement you still need to customize code little bit.

Same for page title you need to extend `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`. You will find [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/override-catalog-page-title) article helpful.

Comment: Got it thanks... I will take a look and see if this works. Appreciate the help